# Error: Access to XMLHttpRequest in React-App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video

I get data from the movie database api. I want to make a movie-app.
I try to upload videos from api. When I start the Video I get an Error:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/962985656/?backend=innertube&cname=56&cver=20230822&foc_id=_IRYSp4auq7hKLvziWVH6w&label=followon_view&ptype=no_rmkt&random=757111354&cv_attributed=0' (redirected from 'https://www.youtube.com/pagead/viewthroughconversion/962985656/?backend=innertube&cname=56&cver=20230822&foc_id=_IRYSp4auq7hKLvziWVH6w&label=followon_view&ptype=no_rmkt&random=757111354') from origin 'https://www.youtube.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. base.js:1915`
`GET https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/962985656/?backend=innertube&cname=56&cver=20230822&foc_id=_IRYSp4auq7hKLvziWVH6w&label=followon_view&ptype=no_rmkt&random=757111354&cv_attributed=0 net::ERR_FAILED 302`

What does it mean. How can I fix this?

MovieDetails.jsx

```js
export default function MovieDetails() {

    const { detail, setDetail } = useContext(Context);

    if(detail !== null){

        return createPortal(
            <div className='moviedetail-Container'>
            
                <div className="video-container">
                {detail.videos.results.map((element) => {
                    if(element.type === "Trailer"){
                        return <Video videoKey={element.key} key={element.key}/>
                    } else {
                        return null
                    }
                })
                }
                </div>
            </div>
        , document.getElementById("movieDetails"));
    } else{
        return null
    }
}
```

Video.jsx

```js
export default function Video(props) {

  return (
    <div className='videos'>
        <iframe src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${props.videoKey}`} frameBorder={0} title={props.videoKey} width={500} height={295} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to enable CORS on backend part